# Python code to stream file contents through socket produces incomplete data

Tags: python, sockets

I've written a simple Python script that reads a file and streams the contents over a socket. The application I've connected to currently just reads the data from the socket and writes it to a file. However the data on the receiving end is incomplete. The first ~150 lines of the file do not get received, nor does the last line. I don't see anything glaringly wrong with my Python code, but if someone can point out what I've done wrong I would appreciate it. If there's an alternative method that can accomplish this task that may be helpful as well. Thanks.

EDIT: I'm pretty sure it's an issue with this code and not the receiving side because I have a C++ version of this Python code that the receiving end works fine with. However, I don't know what could be wrong here.

```
import socket
import sys
import time

__all__=['Stream_File_to_Socket']

def Stream_File_to_Socket(port,input_file):
    # create socket
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server_address = ('localhost',port)


    sock.bind(server_address)
    sock.listen(1)

    # open file and send data
    f = open(input_file,"r")

    while True:
        #print('waiting for a connection')
        connection, client_address = sock.accept()
        if connection.fileno() != -1 :
            break
            #print("no connection!")
            return(-1)

    time.sleep(0.5)
    buffer_size = 1024

    while True:
        data = f.readline()
        if not data:
            connection.send(data)
            break
        connection.send(data)
        time.sleep(0.01)

    f.close()
    return(0)
```

Comment: Why are you assuming that the problem has to be on the sending side?  The only thing I see wrong here is that you aren't explicitly closing the connection, which might explain the missing last line, but not the missing lines at the start.  The problem would therefore appear to be at the receiving end.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong here either. However I have a C++ version of this python code, and the receiving side works just fine with that, so I feel like the problem must be here.